# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, speakers-bureau, sponsorship, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the WordPress community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant WordPress conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: OK, WordCamp Portland has been officially announced for September 17-18 and is actively seeking sponsorships and speakers.  What do I need to do to get SE support for either an official sponsorship or a presentation?  I plan to attend, and I'm more than willing to present on any topic ...

Answer (score 8):

There are several WordCamps throughout the year, some larger than others, and they take place just about everywhere.  A list of upcoming WordCamps from http://WordCamp.org:

- **April 16** - [WordCamp Seattle](http://wordcampseattle.org/) - Seattle, WA
- **May 7** - [WordCamp Switzerland](http://wordcamp-switzerland.ch/) - Brugg, Switzerland
- **May 14** - [WordCamp Orange County](http://2011.oc.wordcamp.org/) - Orange County, CA
- **May 14** - [WordCamp Paris](http://wordcamp.fr/) - Paris, France
- **May 21-22** - [WordCamp Raleigh](http://wordcampraleigh.com/) - Raleigh, NC
- **June 4-5** - [WordCamp Reno-Lake Tahoe](http://2011.reno.wordcamp.org/) - Reno, NV
- **June 11-12** - [WordCamp Kasas City](http://www.wckansascity.org/) - Overland Park, KS
- **June 17-19** - [WordCamp Columbus](http://wordcampcolumbus.com/) - Columbus, OH
- **July 9-10** - [WordCamp Montreal](http://wcmtl.org/) - Montreal, Quebec
- **July 16** - [WordCamp San Diego](http://2011.sandiego.wordcamp.org/) - San Diego, CA
- **July 16-17** - [WordCamp UK](http://uk.wordcamp.org/) - Portsmouth, UK
- **July 23-24** - [WordCamp Boston](http://wordcampboston.com/) - Boston, MA
- **August 12-14** - [WordCamp San Francisco](http://2011.sf.wordcamp.org/) - San Francisco, CA
- **September 12** - [WordCamp Jerusalem](http://wordcampjerusalem.com/) - Jerusalem, Israel
- **September 24** - [WordCamp Lisboa](http://2011.lisboa.wordcamp.org/) - Lisboa, Portugal

I also have it on good authority that [WordCamp Portland](http://www.wordcampportland.org/) will be scheduled for some time this fall ...

Each event is slightly different.  The single-day WordCamps tend to have somewhat structured schedules, a few with many different tracks for speakers (general WordPress knowledge, development, or design).  Multi-day WordCamps might spread the speakers out a bit, then they also have the opportunity for "unconference" sessions - freeform discussions that are decided upon and scheduled the day of the event.

As for the "who" ... **I'd personally be interested in attending any of the above conferences as a speaker and/or representative of the WPSE community**.

Comment: I think @EAMann would be an excellent choice!!! As for me *(which I only mention because I'm also a moderate here)*, I've spoken at many conferences in the past and am a bit burned out on conferences, and I have a foot issue that makes all the walking in travel painful so at least until I can resolve it I wouldn't want to throw my hat in the ring.

Comment: Don't forget Wordcamp UK - 16-17 July 2011 (http://uk.wordcamp.org/)!

Comment: It wasn't on the list at WordCamp.org, but I've added it to the list above :-)

Comment: @all - Anyone from here going to WordCamp UK this year? I will be attending.

Answer (score 1):

*Note before: It might be that i missunderstood the question. If it's about talking about the community or the WA project, then i'm not the one. :)*

I just took a look at **>> May 7 - WordCamp Switzerland - Brugg, Switzerland <<** and have seen that some of the people from our german speaking mailinglist speak there. So I'd be (double) interested in speaking there ([On the agenda still is some white space](http://wordcamp-switzerland.ch/agenda/)).

Point is that I'd have to travel from vienna to brugg, which is expensive and switzerland already isn't cheap. So I would need to know how much you sponsor and if this would be decided before the conference. I guess the white space won't stay forever.

If i can make a workshop/talk, then i would speak about **"Rapid Prototyping with WordPress and a css framework (blueprint)"**.

Comment: Jeff explicitly added that your talk doesn't have to be *about* the site, it should just be something that is *in the scope of* the site. The ideal promotion would be that you insert lines like "When solving this problem I stumbled across this issue, but a quick answer on the WordPress Stack Exchange put me on the right path" :-) And of course, feel free to talk about how great WPSE during the coffee breaks!

Answer (score 0):

What about WordCamp San Francisco? Anyone want to speak there?

http://wordpress.org/news/2011/05/wordcamp-san-francisco-call-for-speakers/

> The annual WordPress conference, WordCamp San Francisco (home of the very first WordCamp), is now accepting speaker applications. Past speakers have included core WordPress developers, people building successful businesses on WordPress, popular bloggers, people from related projects and businesses…you name it. In addition to Matt Mullenweg’s annual “State of the Word” address, WCSF has played host to talks by people like Mark Jaquith, Matt Cutts, Richard Stallman, Scott Berkun, Karl Fogel, Tim Ferriss, Tara Hunt, Chris Pirillo, and John Lilly. With 3 days of content this year instead of just one, the list of speakers should be even more impressive. If you think you’d make a good addition to this year’s roster, check out the [WCSF Call for Speakers](http://2011.sf.wordcamp.org/call-for-speakers/).

Comment: WP San Francisco is the "big poobah" of the WordCamps, and tends to be of a different vein than the rest.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to be going to WordCamp San Fran...

Comment: @mike nice! see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

#### What about providing some level of sponsorship for the actual WordCamp?

[WordCamp Houston](http://www.wordcamphouston.com/) (my hometown) is in the planning stages and will likely be held toward the end of August or beginning of September.  Last year the event was very successful and sold out in less than a week.  This year additional sponsorship funds are needed to help grow the event and accomodate more attendees.

Being an event sponsor would not provide the same direct benefit to a community user being sponsored to attend but it would provide greater exposure for WPSE.  It would also show general good will toward the WordPress community at large.