# No edit link on answer

Tags: support, answers, editing

I'd like to edit [this answer](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/561/possible-conference-speaking-sponsorships-2011/562#562) to add [Wordcamp Israel](http://wordcampjerusalem.com/en/), but I don't see an "edit",  only "link" and "flag".

[image]
 Why?

Comment: I see edit link just fine, screenshot?

Comment: @Rarst Added screenshot

Comment: Hmm, no idea... Do you see edit links on other answers on meta? On main site?

Comment: @Rarst - on meta I don't see any edit links... Can't remember now if I ever have. On the main site I *do* see edit links. I came across a similar question on MSO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link/84676#84676, but I can't see any reason there that would apply to my case :( And BTW, I do see edit links in MSO

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but it might have something to do with your only having ~600 reputation.  I've added WordCamp Jerusalem to the list for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the FAQ shows that you need at least 2000 reputation to edit other people's stuff.  On the main site, when you edit, you're submitting a recommendation that the moderators need to approve.  That's likely why you can't see an edit link on Meta.

That said, on Meta it doesn't hurt to add another answer.  You could just have easily submitted a new answer listing WordCamp Jerusalem, or just left a comment asking someone to add it to my answer.  In any case, it's now added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!